# where am i wrong?? EXC_ARITHMETIC (code = EXC_I386_DIV, subcode = 0x0)

Tags: c++

I can't understand where I'm wrong. I think the error is in the averaging. Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code = EXC_I386_DIV, subcode = 0x0) It returns me this error. Thanks in advance to those who will consider my request.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    
    int m, n; 
    int a[30];
    int somma = 0;
    float media = 0;
    
    for (int i= 0; i<30; i++) {
        cout<<"Inserisci il "<<(i+1)<<" elemento: "<<endl;
        cin>>a[i];
        cout<<endl;
        }
    
    cout<<"Inserisci le variabili m ed n tali che m<x<n"<<endl;
    cout<<"m: ";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"n: ";
    cin>>n;
    
    for (int i= 0; i<30; i++) {
        
        if (a[i]>m && a[i]<n)  {
            somma = somma + a[i];
            media = somma/i;
        }
    }
    
    
    cout<<"La somma è: ";
    cout<<somma<<endl;
    cout<<"La media è: "; 
    cout<<media<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow es un sitio en inglés, escriba en inglés para que las personas puedan responder su pregunta por favor / Stack Overflow is an English site, write in English so people can answer your question please

Comment: @Faissaloo: I'm afraid this is Portuguese: http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Faissaloo it's actually Italian but the point stands (source: i'm Italian)

Comment: @Dominique Thank you for correcting me, I wasn't aware that there was a Portuguese version of the site

Comment: If you don't even know which programming language you are using, there is no hope of ever producing a functioning program.

Comment: @JohnDoe if I initialize i=1, for example, could it work ?

Comment: @Jack it shouldn't crash anymore if that's what you are asking, looking at your code I don't think it will work as you expect anyway though

Comment: @Lundin it was my first time. I'll try to pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i= 0; i<30; i++) {
    
    if (a[i]>m && a[i]<n)  {
        somma = somma + a[i];
        media = somma/i;
    }
}
```

If you successfully enter the `if` statement in the first iteration you try to divide by `0` so your program crashes

Also, you should probably save the number of values you sum to `somma` to calculate the mean.
Let's say only the last number is `true` for `if (a[i]>m && a[i]<n)` and is equal to `10`, in that case you would have

```
if (10>m && 10<n)  {
    somma = somma + 10;
    media = somma/29;
}
```

Which will give you 0.344... even if you summed only 1 number

something like this could work

```
int values = 0;

for (int i= 0; i<30; i++) {

    if (a[i]>m && a[i]<n)  {
        somma = somma + a[i];
        ++values;
        media = somma/values;
    }
}
```

and give you the mean of the summed values